# F12 Developer Tools - locating Inline Style

Tags: html

Looking at the `F12 Developer Tools` - I can see that it helps identify where some styles come from with the reference of the right (**style.css** for example) but where does the `Inline style` come from?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A [style attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-style-attribute) (or the [DOM style property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)).

```
<p style="Width: 298px;">
```

Comment: Thanks but what I am asking is where do I look in my code to find where this style is set?

Comment: @RichardGriffiths — The HTML or the JavaScript depending on which one set it.

Comment: OK - I was just hoping it might be a little more specific. Trawling through loads of JavaScript .... I'll just keep looking. Thanks.